# The long term behavior for iterating linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Supoose $f=mx+c$ if and only if $(m,c) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

a) the function iterates converge for all initial value $x_{0}$.

b) the function iterates converge for more than one initial value.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please clarify.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score -1):

The $n$-th iterate yields $m^nx+(m^{n-1}+m^{n-2}+\cdots+m+1)c=m^nx+\frac{m^n-1}{m-1}c$, the last equality being valid only if $m \neq 1$, which converges regardless of $x$ if and only if:

$\bullet$ $|m|<1$ to $\frac{c}{1-m}$

or

$\bullet $ $m=1$ and $c=0$ to $x$

For $|m|>1$, it converges only for a specific value of $x$ which makes the term in $m^n$ vanish:

$\bullet$ $|m|>1$ and $x=\frac{c}{1-m}$, which converges to $\frac{c}{1-m}$